# excel vba worksheetfunction.sum

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I have a function which should calculate the sum in an array of cells. This function is called in another subroutine very often and therefore has to be real fast. First I used a for-loop to get the numbers but it was too slow. Then I wanted to use a worksheetfunction but this is not working for reasons unknown. Here is the code of the function:

```
Function CalcMD(rownumbers, colnumber)

Dim MMDRow As Integer
Dim SearchRange As String
Dim FirstAddress As Boolean

MMDRow = MMDRow()
FirstAddress = False
SearchRange = ""

'building the search range
For i = 0 To UBound(rownumbers)
    If rownumbers(i) > 0 And rownumbers(i) < MMDRow Then
        If FirstAddress = False Then
            SearchRange = SearchRange & cells(rownumbers(i), colnumber).Address(False, False)
            FirstAddress = True
        Else
            SearchRange = SearchRange & ";" & cells(rownumbers(i), colnumber).Address(False, False)
        End If
    End If
Next

CalcMD = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(SearchRange))

End Function
```

Is there a better/faster way to get this result?

Comment: what is  `MMDRow()`? And seeing a screenshot, or worked example of what you want to achieve would be handy :)

Comment: I get an array of all rownumbers where a certain name is in the cell. But I dont want the last row where this name is because this contains the cell for the sum of the other rows. The function calculates the sum of man days in a monthly column. If this value is more than the maximum allowed value I have to decrease the values in this column. After every decrease I call the function to check if the sum is equal to the maximum allowed value. Therefore it has to be real fast. I hope this helps.

Comment: MMDRow() is another function which gets the row above the sums.

Comment: If the last row has the sum of all other rows then why not just divide the sum of all rows by two to get the number you want?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If you are using 2007 and above you can just use SumIfs function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try. The trickiest part is finding the last row you want to sum, I think this is where we should work if this first attempt doesn't solve your case.

```
Function CalcMD(rownumbers, colnumber)

    Dim MMDRow As Integer, iMaxRow As Integer
    Dim SearchRange As String

    MMDRow = MMDRow()

    'Find the last row where you want to sum the data
    iMaxRow = WorksheetFunction.Min(MMDRow - 1, WorksheetFunction.Max(rownumbers))

    CalcMD = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(iMaxRow, colnumber))

End Function
```

Please also note that there aren't many error checking here (especially to check the input data)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and it doesn't work because you are trying to find the cell where the sum is. I don't want to find this cell. I want to calculate over the rowarray what the sum actually is because the formula in the last row may not be updated accordingly and then I would have a wrong sum to distribute. I have to iterate over all rows, add all values and retrieve the sum.

Comment: I think I have a better idea. I calculate the difference and call the function once and then do while until difference is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Using JMax's approach:

```
Function CalcMD(rownumbers, colnumber)

    Dim MMDRow As Integer, iMaxRow As Integer
    Dim SearchRange As String

    MMDRow = MMDRow()

    'Find the last row where you want to sum the data
    iMaxRow = WorksheetFunction.Min(MMDRow - 1, WorksheetFunction.Max(rownumbers))

    CalcMD = WorksheetFunction.SumIF(Cells(iMaxRow, colnumber),">0")

End Function
```

Is that what you are looking for?